# Creating multiple array lists

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Re-worded objective**:
I'm creating a web page using google apps script. I want to have multiple drop downs listed on the page. I know if I use `<select><option>`, I can create a list of hard coded options. What I would rather do is grab the options from a google sheet to display in the drop down, this way I can update it at anytime without modifying the HTML code.

**The issue:** While I was successful in creating a drop down selection containing Column A values from my sheet, I'm running into an issue where Apps Script will not let me create another drop down containing the values of Column B.

This is my sheet that contains names and dietary types. Each column contains the options for each drop down.

[image]

This is what it looks like on the front end. I'd like to have another drop down beside it that contains values from Column B (as seen above).

[image]

Here is my script:

```
var url = "google sheets URL";

function doGet(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Staff");
  var list = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();

  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  tmp.list = list.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  return tmp.evaluate();

}
```

This is the HTML for my selection list:

```
  <select id="app" class="browser-default">
  <option disabled selected>Select a teammate!</option>
  <? for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){ ?>
  <option><?= list[i]; ?></option>
  <? } ?>
  </select>
```

It functions correctly at this point but when trying to replicate it so I can grab another column in Google Sheets and use that as another selection list,
I get: Referenceerror: "list" is not defined.

This is the script that's causing me to get the error.

```
var url = "google sheets URL";

function doGet(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Staff");
  var list = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();

  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  tmp.list = list.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  return tmp.evaluate();

}

function doGet(f){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Variables");
  var list2 = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();

  var tmp2 = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  tmp2.list2 = list2.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  return tmp2.evaluate();

}
```

Comment: Is `<? for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){ ?>` PHP? If so, it's not valid PHP.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint before list gets populated? Odds are it's null or undefined and you can know for sure by stepping through the code at execution.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? It seems that in your script, there are 2 functions of `doGet`. When the same function names are used in a GAS project, only one of them is run. Is this situation related to your issue? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, I was able to get it working by creating new functions for each one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a simple example of getting multiple list from a dialog.**

Load the code and run launchDialog().  You could also add a doGet() and use `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq4');`

Code.gs:

```
function getList(n) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,n,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  return rg.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
}

function launchDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq4');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'My List');
}
```

aq4.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    input{margin:5px;}
    td,th{border:1px solid black;}
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
        }
      })
      .getList(1);
    });
    function getAnotherList() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
        }
      })
      .getList(Math.floor(Math.random()*23));
    }
    console.log("My Code");
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <select id="sel1"></select>
  <input type="button" value="Get Another List" onClick="getAnotherList();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my List Spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: Hey Cooper! This does work for google sheets, but I'm trying to output this as a webpage that doesn't load from within google sheets, but rather retrieves the information from there. I'll update my original post with images and reword my goal. Thank you for this answer though, I didn't know that we could essentially use HTML to create the popup dialog for scripts. Will definitely be using this in another project!